# How do I see if a method never gets called in Visual C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, overriding, visual-studio-2017, app.xaml

I've recently discovered that `0 references` above a method in Visual Studio can be misleading. I've been relying on it to find extra methods that are no longer used, but now I don't know if it's reliable.

`OnStartup()` in App.xaml.cs says 0 references even though it must be called since it's often used as an entry point. Why is that? Are references only found if they're in your own project and not outside code? Can I be sure this problem only happens with `override` methods?

I experimented with similar virtual and override methods in my own classes and the references showed up just fine.

Is there any way to tell for sure if a method is never called from anywhere?

Comment: Seems like these references are pointing to user code, and not framework related code calls. I tend to double check with Resharper, however sometimes you just need to know or use trial&error approach.

Comment: There's lots of ways a method can be called without any way to tell (e.g. reflection) so the only guarantee is to add metrics to your app and log it.

Comment: ReSharper is a great extension for Visual Studio that can do this for you..it is not free however.

Comment: Reflection is the quirk, it cannot be analyzed by a static code analyzer.   Not ReSharper either.  Yes, applies to OnStartup.  You don't have a real problem.

Comment: You can add a debug message to the method or just apply a break point.  If this is for a released application then insert a log.  If you have a method that isn't used and it's public then it must be part of the app.  If it's in a library I don't believe this is the correct behavior.  It's common to have method unused until they applied to another project as a package / library.  Can you post the code and describe the project it is in?  I'm a little bit confused.

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII There's nothing to describe. Have you not seen an OnStartup() method in App.xaml.cs before? Also, debug messages and break points would not work because a method might run only in certain circumstances. Not every method is sure to run every time you run an application.

Comment: Can reflection be used to access private methods?

Comment: Yes, reflection can access anything about a type.

Comment: @DavidG Besides reflection, how else might a method be called without any references showing up?